# Stack object in one method does not seem to be the same as in another in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, data-structures, stack

I have a piece of code like this. The problem is that push and pop are not working together. Actually, I think push method working well but there is a problem with pop. Because when the object trigged stack.count increase 1 but when click the button in the canvas ,console print "The Stack is Empty" and stack.count = 0.  What is the problem here ?

```
    Stack<Skill> stackSkills;
   
    void Start()
    {
        stackSkills= new Stack<Skill>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider){
     
            stackSkills.Push(newSkill);
            Debug.Log(stackSkills.Count); //When i trigger it , it increases.
    }

    public void OnClick(){

        Debug.Log("clicked");
        Debug.Log(stackSkills.Count);
        stackSkills.Pop();
        
    }
}
```

Here is the example:
OUTPUT

```
1
2
3
clicked
0
InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
System.Collections.Generic.Stack1[T].ThrowForEmptyStack () (at <ef151b6abb5d474cb2c1cb8906a8b5a4>:0)
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted would explain the output you claim to get. Assuming the output is accurately described, then either the `stackSkills` field value is being replaced with a new object, the original object is being cleared elsewhere, or the `skillController` instance that is handling the `OnTriggerEnter()` method call is a different instance from the one that is handling the `OnClick()` method call. Given how Unity3d works, I'd put my money on that last one, but really there's no way for any of us reading your question to know one way or the other.

Comment: OMG i guess you are right. i have used `OnClick()` and `OnTriggerEnter()` in two different game object.And they are not sharing same data field even they are not same instance.Thanks for your correction. @PeterDuniho . Now How can i sign the topic as SOLVED? :) it was my first question idk how it works

Comment: You can post an answer yourself, and then select the checkmark ("accepted") button to indicate that it's the solution to your problem. If you do so, please consider rewording the title to be more descriptive of the actual problem (e.g. "Stack object in one method does not seem to be the same as in another", or something like that) so that it's easier for others who may have a similar problem in the future to find your question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this problem happens is to use this same script in different two Game Object (Canvas and myGameObject) and they are not linked with each other.I am calling `OnTriggerEnter()` method in myGameObject and `OnClick()` method in Canvas. Therefore they are not sharing same data fields. There is two Stack in the project.